# Attempting to Translate a Google From into a PDF Document that Then emails and am having script errors

Tags: google-apps-script

So I am attempting to take the information from a google form that translates to a google spreadsheet to a google document that then converts to PDF and emails to the initial sender on submit.

I have the code written and am having an issue after the creation of the new document that is ment to be sent. The code is not finding the document that needs to be filled.
Below is the code followed by the error I am receiving. It is on line 23.

```
var docTemplate = "1mlAPTZ_UH1I3bRfgqiOVDI7PKgDXV-tGMpXLIwFoPjQ";
var docName = "Downtime";
function onFormSubmit (e) {
var Email_Address = e.values[2];
var Character_and_Player_Name = e.values[1];
var Major_Events_for_your_Character_Last_Session = e.values[3];
var Feedback_and_Questions = e.values[4];
var Major_Downtime_Action_A = e.values[5];
var Major_Downtime_Action_B = e.values[6];
var Major_Downtime_Action_C = e.values[7];
var Minor_Action_A = e.values[8];
var Minor_Action_B = e.values[9];
var Minor_Action_C = e.values[10];
var Minor_Action_D = e.values[11];
var Minor_Action_E = e.values[12];
var Minor_Action_F = e.values[13];
var Pack_Downtime = e.values[14];
var XP_Spends = e.values[15];
var Renown = e.values[16];
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+Character_and_Player_Name)
.getId();
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openByID(copyId);
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
copybody.replaceText('keyCharacterandPlayerName', Character_and_Player_Name);
copybody.replaceText('keyMajorEventsforyourCharacterLastSession', Major_Events_for_your_Character_Last_Session);
copybody.replaceText('keyFeedbackandQuestion', Feedback_and_Questions);
copybody.replaceText('keyMajorDowntimeActionA', Major_Downtime_Action_A);
copybody.replaceText('keyMajorDowntimeActionB', Major_Downtime_Action_B);
copybody.replaceText('keyMajorDowntimeActionC', Major_Downtime_Action_C);
copybody.replaceText('keyMinorActionA', Minor_Action_A);
copybody.replaceText('keyMinorActionB', Minor_Action_B);
copybody.replaceText('keyMinorActionC', Minor_Action_C);
copybody.replaceText('keyMinorActionD', Minor_Action_D);
copybody.replaceText('keyMinorActionE', Minor_Action_E);
copybody.replaceText('keyMinorActionF', Minor_Action_F);
copybody.replaceText('keyPackDowntim', Pack_Downtime);
copybody.replaceText('keyXPSpends', XP_Spends);
copybody.replaceText('keyRenown', Renown);
copyDoc.saveAndClose();
var pdf = DocsList.getFileByID(copyID) .getAs("application/pdf");
var subject = "Downtime Copy"
var body = "Here is a copy of your submitted Downtime for Rage Across the Dunes for " + Character_and_Player_Name;
MailApp.sendEmail(Email_Address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
DocsList.getFileById(copyID).setTrashed(true);
}
```

---

TypeError: Cannot find function openByID in object DocumentApp. (line 23, file "Code")

Any help would be great I am learning as I go so any help would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Change the capital "D" to a lower case "d".

ID to Id

```
DocumentApp.openByID(copyId)
```

Needs to be:

```
DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
```